# Sql query to find not present in 1 n relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables product table and status table

and there is 1 ton n relation

```
Product table
----------------------
id    | product
1           XYZ
2           ABC
3           HJK
4           PQR
5           SWE

----------------------

status_table
--------------------------------
id  | col1 | col2 | priduct_id
2      s1     ss1      2
3      s2     xs1      3   
5      s1     ss1      3          
4      s1     xs1      4
4      s3     xs2      4
4      s2     ss2      4
4      s3     xs2      4                 
5      ww     sw2      5                   
-------------------------------------
```

i want to select all product where status NOT EQUAL =  S3

i tried This

```
select product_Table.product from product_Table
inner join status_table on 
product_table.id = status_table.id
where status_table.col1 <> 's3'
```

Comment: Is that `status_table.col1`? Also, do you want products with no status records or *only* those with status records as long as they aren't "S3"?

Comment: What queries did you try? Can you show us examples that you tried and did not work?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` should do it, it matches rows from status_table with status `s3` with each product, and if no matching status exists, returns the product;

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.product
FROM product_table p
LEFT JOIN status_table s
  ON p.id = s.product_id
 AND s.col1 = 's3'
WHERE s.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of inconsistencies in your table design (naming etc) but anyhow, have you tried something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE id NOT IN
 ( SELECT priduct_id
   FROM status_table
   WHERE col1 <> 'S3');
```

Comment: Phil - no it won't. It will only select as many records as there are Products

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT P.id, Product, col1
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN status_table S
ON P.id = S.product_id
WHERE S.col1 <> 's3'
```

Comment: This will skip product "XYZ" but I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select product_Table.product from product_Table
inner join status_table on 
product_table.id = status_table.id
where 
status_table.col1 <> 's3'
group by 
product_Table.product
```

Please check [My Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6059a/4)

Comment: Someone (not me) downvoted your answer because you just post a link without putting your answer here. It's ok to post a link but it should be coupled with your actual answer. The reason for that if the link is dead or is wrong then at least your answer could still be seen.

Comment: wrong answer , just for example let product id 3 has result s2,s3,s4 then also it show product id 3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting back products with no status associations (like "XYZ"), try this

```
SELECT p.id, p.product FROM Product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM status_table s
    WHERE s.priduct_id = p.id
    AND s.col1 = 's3'
)
```